# If $A=\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n dx , n\in\mathbb{N}$, then Pick out the correct statement(s)...

Tags: integration, analysis

If $A=\int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n dx , n\in\mathbb{N}$, then Pick out the correct statements

(1) A in not an rational number

(2) $0< A\leq 4^{-n}$

(3) A is a natural number

(4) $A^{-1}$ is a natural number

We can omit the option (1) and $(3)$ because $A=1/2$ for $n=1$. Also given $A$ is beta function, that is $A=\frac{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(n+1)}{\Gamma(2n+2)}$, using this hoe to find correct option. help me!

Answer (score 4):

As regards (2), note that $0\leq x(1-x)\leq 4^{-1}$ in $[0,1]$, hence
$$0\leq \int_0^1 x^n(1-x)^n dx\leq \int_0^1 4^{-n} dx=4^{-n}.$$

As regards (4), since $\Gamma(m+1)=m!$ for $m\in \mathbb{N}$, then
$$A^{-1}=\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^2}=(2n+1)\cdot \binom{2n}{n}\in \mathbb{N}.$$

Moreover $A^{-1}\geq 6$ which excludes (3) ($A=1/6$ for $n=1$).

(4) implies that (1) is false.